# Control.Slider is not a constructor New Extension Problem 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, prototype-js

I have just paid $150 for an extension from MageStore (Reward Points Plus) and it is not working.

The error I am getting is:

```
prototype.js:828 Uncaught TypeError: Control.Slider is not a constructor
```

In the extension JS the code is:

```
    var RewardPointsSlider = Class.create();
RewardPointsSlider.prototype = {
    initialize: function (pointEl, trackEl, handleEl, zoomOutEl, zoomInEl, pointLbl) {
        this.pointEl = $(pointEl);
        this.trackEl = $(trackEl);
        this.handleEl = $(handleEl);
        this.pointLbl = $(pointLbl);

        this.minPoints = 0;
        this.maxPoints = 1;
        this.pointStep = 1;

        this.slider = new Control.Slider(this.handleEl, this.trackEl, {
            axis: 'horizontal',
            range: $R(this.minPoints, this.maxPoints),
            values: this.availableValue(),
            onSlide: this.changePoint.bind(this),
            onChange: this.changePoint.bind(this)
        });
        this.changePointCallback = function (v) {
        };

        Event.observe($(zoomOutEl), 'click', this.zoomOut.bind(this));
        Event.observe($(zoomInEl), 'click', this.zoomIn.bind(this));
    },
    availableValue: function () {
        var values = [];
        for (var i = this.minPoints; i <= this.maxPoints; i += this.pointStep) {
            values.push(i);
        }
        return values;
    },
    applyOptions: function (options) {
        this.minPoints = options.minPoints || this.minPoints;
        this.maxPoints = options.maxPoints || this.maxPoints;
        this.pointStep = options.pointStep || this.pointStep;

        this.slider.range = $R(this.minPoints, this.maxPoints);
        this.slider.allowedValues = this.availableValue();

        this.manualChange(this.slider.value);
    },
    changePoint: function (points) {
        this.pointEl.value = points;
        if (this.pointLbl) {
            this.pointLbl.innerHTML = points;
        }
        if (typeof this.changePointCallback == 'function') {
            this.changePointCallback(points);
        }
    },
    zoomOut: function () {
        var curVal = this.slider.value - this.pointStep;
        if (curVal >= this.minPoints) {
            this.slider.value = curVal;
            this.slider.setValue(curVal);
            this.changePoint(curVal);
        }
    },
    zoomIn: function () {
        var curVal = this.slider.value + this.pointStep;
        if (curVal <= this.maxPoints) {
            this.slider.value = curVal;
            this.slider.setValue(curVal);
            this.changePoint(curVal);
        }
    },
    manualChange: function (points) {
        points = this.slider.getNearestValue(parseInt(points));
        this.slider.value = points;
        this.slider.setValue(points);
        this.changePoint(points);
    },
    changeUseMaxpoint: function (event) {
        var checkEl = event.element();
        if (checkEl.checked) {
            this.manualChange(this.maxPoints);
        } else {
            this.manualChange(0);
        }
    },
    changeUseMaxpointEvent: function (checkEl) {
        Event.observe($(checkEl), 'click', this.changeUseMaxpoint.bind(this));
    },
    manualChangePoint: function (event) {
        var changeEl = event.element();
        this.manualChange(changeEl.value);
    },
    manualChangePointEvent: function (changeEl) {
        Event.observe($(changeEl), 'change', this.manualChangePoint.bind(this));
    }
}
```

This controls the slider to add discount to the order.

I have contacted Magestore who are not willing to help me until next week as they are on holiday.

Comment: control class not loaded find controller class in that package js file and check

Comment: I have added the information I think. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: bro I think `Control` class is not loaded please check that class and add that js or contact your extension provider

Comment: Sorry I dont know what to look for :(

Comment: in this code you have this line ` this.slider = new Control.Slider(this.handleEl, this.trackEl,{` for this line to run code is looking for some `Control` class becuase it creating an object of that class and that class is missing

Comment: OK so where should this class be or how do I find it? It what type of file?

Comment: search in js folder in magento root

Comment: i have all the files locally. the only js file is rewardpoints.js, that is where I got my code from